# How to remove header names from each rows in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm reading an Html file using Pandas data-frame. Everything going well - the only problem I'm facing is, that all the header's names are getting appended to each row.
Please tell me why is this happening and how I can resolve it.
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Please share some of the input and the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
>>> df
          THUMBNAIL     NAME
0  THUMBNAILxyz.png  NAMExyz
1  THUMBNAILabc.png  NAMEabc

# Solution 1
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.str[len(x.name):])
  THUMBNAIL NAME
0   xyz.png  xyz
1   abc.png  abc

# Solution 2
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lstrip(x.name))
  THUMBNAIL NAME
0   xyz.png  xyz
1   abc.png  abc

# Solution 3
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(x.name, ''))
  THUMBNAIL NAME
0   xyz.png  xyz
1   abc.png  abc

# Solution 4
>>> df.apply(lambda x: x.str.extract(fr"{x.name}(.*)", expand=False))
  THUMBNAIL NAME
0   xyz.png  xyz
1   abc.png  abc
```

And so on.

Comment: Hi Corralien: Thank you! It really worksed for me.

Comment: Glad to read that :)